# UDP bind: Address already in use

Tags: c++, node.js, udp, boost-asio

I have no knowledge in `node.js`.

I am sending `UDP` packets in `C++` and I want to show them in `node.js`.

The problem is that both try to occupy the IP/port. Depending on which one I run, the other one fails. How should I fix this problem?

main.cpp

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++11 -lboost_system -pthread

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    const int port=1414;
    const std::string ip="127.0.0.1";

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::resolver resolver(io_service);

    udp::endpoint client_endpoint = *resolver.resolve({udp::v4(), ip, std::to_string(port)});
    udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
    boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
    socket.set_option(option);

    std::string data;
    for(long i=0;true;i++)
    {
        data=std::to_string(i+1)+"th packet";
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data.c_str(), data.length()+1), client_endpoint);
        usleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

app.js

```
var PORT = 1414;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

If I run the `C++` file and then the `js` one, the error is this:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:1414
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at dgram.js:221:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

While, if I run the `js` file first and then the `C++` one, I receive:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  bind: Address already in use
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use two different ports. If one of the peers is a client it doesn't need a fixed port number.

Comment: @EJP, How can I send data to one port and receive it from another port?

Comment: You don't have to. The client sends to the server port, and receives at its own port. The server sends responsese back to the remote IP:port the request was received from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`reuseAddr: true`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dgram.html#dgram_dgram_createsocket_options_callback) when creating your socket:

```
var server = dgram.createSocket({ type: 'udp4', reuseAddr: true });
```

You will also need to change how you create your socket on the C++ side. Currently the `udp::socket` constructor signature you're using will cause the socket to bind immediately. Unfortunately, you need to set the `reuse_address` option first *before* binding. To do that, try this intead:

```cpp
udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::v4());
socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
socket.bind(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now if I run `cpp` then `js`. How to fix it from `C++` side as well so I can call `js` and then `cpp` too.

Answer (score 2):

What @mscdex wrote is correct, but what @EJP's suggested is a more standard way of doing what you're (I believe) trying to accomplish.

That is, you normally have only the server on a well known port such as 1414 and clients usually start on any random port that is not already used.

To do that, you don't need to change your js code, and only change this part of c++ code:

```
udp::endpoint client_endpoint
    = *resolver.resolve({udp::v4(), ip, std::to_string(port)});
udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

to:

```
udp::endpoint client_endpoint
    = *resolver.resolve({udp::v4(), ip, std::to_string(port)});
// Passing 0 as the port argument will tell the system to
// pick a random port for you.
udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));
```