# NodeJs receive UDP numbers in ugly binary format

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, casting, binary

I have no knowledge in `node.js`.

After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262716/udp-bind-address-already-in-use) about how to send `UDP` string text with `C++` and receive it from `Node.js`, I am thinking about receiving numbers (and even more generally, receiving objects).

The results I get are ugly characters with binary format. How should I fix them?

Results:

```
127.0.0.1:1414 - (�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ףp=
(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �G�z(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ��Q�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - \���((�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - 33333(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - 
ףp=(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �z�G(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ���Q(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ���(\(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - gffff(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - >
ףp(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �G�z(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �Q��(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ��(\�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �����(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - q=
ף(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - H�z�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ��Q�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �(\��(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �����(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �p=
�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - {�G�(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - R���(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - )\���(�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - )�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ףp=
)�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - �G�z)�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - ��Q�)�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - \���()�@
127.0.0.1:1414 - 33333)�@
127.0.0.1:1414 -
```

app.js

```
var PORT = 1414;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket({ type: 'udp4', reuseAddr: true });

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

main.cpp

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++11 -lboost_system -pthread

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    const int port=1414;
    const std::string ip="127.0.0.1";

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::resolver resolver(io_service);

    udp::endpoint client_endpoint = *resolver.resolve({udp::v4(), ip, std::to_string(port)});
    udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::v4());
    socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
    socket.bind(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));

    double data;
    for(long i=0;true;i++)
    {
        data=i*0.01;
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer((char *)&data, sizeof(data)), client_endpoint);
        usleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the receiving end is interpreting your `double` as a string. You need to reinterpret the message as a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are receiving are [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html)s, which contain binary data. By concatenating `message` with a string, you are implicitly calling `message.toString()` which by default will convert the binary data to UTF8, which is what you are seeing.

Instead what you will need to do is read directly from `message`. You can read numbers from a `Buffer` using the `message.read*()` methods.

There is a problem you will still encounter with your current code however: the order in which your `data` bytes are being sent is dependent upon the host's CPU (type). It's best to send data over a network in network byte order (big endian) to ensure compatibility and consistency.

Assuming however you are running on say a typical Intel or AMD CPU, you *should* be able to use [`message.readDoubleLE()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readdoublele_offset_noassert) on the node.js side to read the value.